# Maven using proxy for hosts configured with noProxyHost

Tags: maven, proxy

I have the following setup: I have a maven (3.3.3) project with different dependencies:

1. Dependencies that have to be downloaded from the public internet.
2. Dependencies that have to be downloaded from the intranet.

Regarding proxies, they have to be handled differently:

- Because the maven build happens in the private intranet, all download form the public internet have to be downloaded via a proxy.
- The servers in the intranet do now allow public access. For this reasons all downloads from the intranet have to be downloaded without proxy.

Luckily the intranet servers are easily identifiable because their domain ends in `.thecompany.org`.

I run my maven project, and get errors for dependencies from the internet (because the proxy settings are missing).

So in my `.2m/settings.xml` I do:

```
<proxies>
<proxy>
    <id>internet-proxy</id>
    <active>true</active>
    <protocol>http</protocol>
    <host>proxy-server.org</host>
    <port>8080</port>
    <nonProxyHosts>localhost|*.thecompany.org</nonProxyHosts>
</proxy>
</proxies>
```

Now I run maven and get "Access Denied" errors for the downloads from the intranet. But the files maven wants to download are reachable (I can confirm that with wget). The "Access Denied" happens, when I try to download via proxy.

So it seems, that Maven is using the proxy. When I look at the logs, I see this

```
[DEBUG] Using connector BasicRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for http://server.thecompany.org/somedir/
```

and for the external connections, it would tell me that it uses a proxy.

Could it be that Maven uses a proxy without telling me?

Answer (score 0):

I use a Maven repository manager like Nexus to combine all my upstream repositories into a single repository group.

- https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/maven.html#_grouping_maven_repositories

So configure the repository on the Maven repository and point all Maven clients to a single repository that aggregates all the upstream repo sources.

An important secondary benefit of a Maven repository is that it will cache dependencies thereby speeding up your build.